# Message displayed to clients as they connect but before they log in?

Tags: ssh, motd

I do not need to modify or create a message for the VM, I just need to find out what the message already is. I have looked into the MOTD directory using /etc/update-motd.d/ but the message was not there in any file.

Comment: I can't work out what you are asking. Something about message of the day. Is it being displayed when you login? Are you asking how to display it before the user logs in (before password)? p.s. don't use password authentication.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It is possible that the message is not stored in MOTD. I have to answer a question for an Ubuntu Image and the question states "What is the very first message that is displayed to clients as soon as they connect (before logging in)". I am just confused as to where to look.

Comment: @JackHudetz, when they connect _with what_?

Comment: Maybe they want you to look at the sshd config. Can you edit your question to include the complete text of your assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Message of the day is in `/etc/motd`.

If it is another message, then find it with.

```
find /etc -mount -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F 'some text from the message'
```

Comment: Isn't that displayed *after* authentication?  with `/etc/issue` emitted before.

Comment: @TobySpeight if that is where the message is stored. They our should add it as an answer. I only explained how to find it (and where the message of the day is).